# How to restore bhakti after you stopped praying for a long time?

Tags: krishna, sri-vaishnava, bhakti, ramanujacharya, vishishtadvaita

I am an aspiring Sri Vaishnava in an Asian foreign country with the least minimum Sri Vaishnavas around for guidance and I have never met anyone except the temple priests from the local Perumal temples.

I used to pray and read the needful but one day, after a year or so, I stopped praying altogether for months after I had a personal conflict in my life(which has now resolved). I still listened to Narayaneeyam discourses on YouTube but it's just that. I feel nothing. I even stopped going to the altar in the house or even to the temples. I want to return to the path of devotion again.

Yesterday, I went to our local Venkateswara temple and I prayed but I didn't feel anything. I felt like my heart was dry, devoid of any love towards the Lord or His consort.

Please guide me. I don't have an Acharya as I have not taken Pancha Samskaram yet.

Comment: The sensitiveness perception which developed through particular period of practice goes down if it is stopped just like a bowl which becomes dirty next day after cleaning. The evolution of your Atma is important and just like bathing for body engaging in steadfast Yoga with Paramatma is essential for clean mental health. This is like falling from 12th floor after you have done something to reach a certain height. You will not feel anything if you restart again. But slow steady progress daily routine with Vishnu after bath, can again rise your sensitiveness to these!! So. TO CONTD!

Comment: So to restart, start again like how you do earlier. Dont look at results. Just focus on what action you should do for it!!!!

Comment: Where Bhakti/devotion fails, Gyan/wisdom works. Try building Viveka(wisdom) and Vairagya(renunciation) through reading Geeta, Yoga Vasistha or Upanishads. Devotion and Wisdom both lead to the same destination.

Comment: I think the best way to restart your bhakti is through shravana i.e. listening to His glories in pravachanas and keerthanas. There are lot good pravachanas available on YouTube, for example pravachanas by Dushyanth Sridhar.